# Updating Wix Bootstrapper variables from MsiPackage

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, bootstrapper

Is it possible to update variables in a wix bootstrapper form an MSIPackage which it executes? I have some variables that are being set in the MSIPackage that I need to pass back up to another MSIPackage.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible today in WiX v3 or v4. The WiX bootstrapper (Burn) is meant to be used with "dumb" MSI's, the Bootstrapper Application (BA) is supposed to decide the values of MSI Properties.